# Obtaining the correct date using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, date

01/02/2018 12:25:00 PM

I have the above date which is in an Excel spreadsheet's B1 cell. The date is 01 February 2018 but the VBA code below

```
thedate = CDate(Application.Cells(linecount, 2))
```

converts this to 02 January 2018

What VBA code do I use to have this remain 01 February 2018?

Comment: where are you getting this date?  Which data type is it in?

Comment: @ashleedawg I edited the question to make it better . I hope that you are able to help,

Comment: Are your regional settings correct?  When I try it it remains as 1st February.  Also `Application.Cells` will refer to the currently active sheet in the workbook - you could leave out the `Application` part and it will work the same.  It's better to be specific about which sheet you're referring to:  `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(linecount,2)`,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use VBA to return a `Date` data type value of string `01/02/2018 12:25:00 PM` representing `01 February 2018` in your local regional date settings (in a message box), you could use:

```
Dim dt as String
dt = "01/02/2018 12:25:00 PM"
MsgBox DateSerial(Mid(dt, 7, 4), Mid(dt, 4, 2), Left(dt, 2))
```

[image: img]  <sup>**†**</sup> <sub>*This is how it displays for **me**.  See note below.*</sub>

If you actually want a string to be returned (in a messages box) in the specific format you mentioned, `"dd MMMM yyyy"`, you could use:

```
Dim dt as String
dt = "01/02/2018 12:25:00 PM"
MsgBox Format(DateSerial(Mid(dt, 7, 4), Mid(dt, 4, 2), Left(dt, 2)), "dd MMMM yyyy")
```

[image: img]

If you wanted to *store* this data (including the time), or use it for calculations, then the ***proper*** way to do it would be more like:

```
Dim strMyDate as String, dtMyDate as Date
strMyDate = "01/02/2018 12:25:00 PM"
dtMyDate = DateSerial(Mid(strMyDate, 7, 4), Mid(strMyDate, 4, 2), _
    Left(strMyDate, 2)) + TimeValue(Mid(strMyDate, 11))
MsgBox dtMyDate
```

[image: img]

---

<sup>**†**</sup> Note that these MsgBox's are displaying date/time's based on *my* system's Windows settings (shown below), shown here, where they could be adjusted if required.  (Hence, the results above will appear differently for you.)

- Open these settings by hitting <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> type `region`, and hit <kbd>ᴇɴᴛᴇʀ</kbd>.

  <sub>(Click to enlarge)</sub>
  [image]
- The DateTime is actually stored in Excel as a number where `0` = `December 30, 1899` and `+1 = +1 day`, so your example date of `01 February 2018 12:25:00 PM` is actually only a formatted representation of the DateTime serial number, in this case,  `43132.5173611`.

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**DateSerial function** (VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dateserial-function)
- MSDN : [**Format function** (VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications)
- MSDN : [**TimeValue function** (VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/timevalue-function)
- Microsoft.com : [**How to use dates and times in Excel**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214094/how-to-use-dates-and-times-in-excel)